# How to compute multiplication in $ \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: algorithms, multiplication, modular-arithmetic

Good day,

I have heard about the [Montgomery modular multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication), and the [Barrett_reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction); (or any other) But in practice I don't understand how could I implement a multiplication algorithm in a Ring modulo n.

I am looking for such algorithm in an JavaScript environment using an accumulator.

**Edit:** I found what I was looking for:
To multiply A x B mod M: (Ai being each digits of A from left to right)

```
acc <- B * A0
i<-1
While i <= A.length-1 do
   acc <- (acc * 10 + B * Ai)
   while acc>= M do acc-= M end
   i++
End
Return acc
```

Comment: We don't answer questions about specific languages. Also, why would you use an accumulator? The simplest solution is to use a standard library.